# Combine strings into one

Tags: r

Is there a way to convert all strings into one. For example

```
asds <- c("as","asd","sdff")
asds
[1] "as"   "asd"  "sdff"
```

Expected output

```
asds
'as asd sdff'
```

I just tried with below code but getting the error

```
> asds <- c("as","asd","sdff")
> paste: paste(asds, collapse=" ")
Error in paste:paste(asds, collapse = " ") : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Use `paste`: `paste(asds, collapse=" ")`

Comment: Thanks. But i got the below error ````paste: paste(asds)
Error in paste:paste(asds) : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In paste:paste(asds) :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
2: NAs introduced by coercion ````

Comment: Provide reproducible example data that produces this error. `dput(asds)`

Comment: Edited my code...

Comment: Remove "paste:"

Comment: Do not copy “paste:”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**  comment of OP:

wrap `toString` around:

`toString(glue_collapse(asds, sep = " "))`

**Alternative** use `stri_join` from `stringi` package

```
library(stringi)
stri_join(asds, collapse=' ')

# output:
[1] "as asd sdff"
```

**First answer:**

We could use `glue_collapse`

```
glue_collapse(asds, sep = " ")
```

output:

```
as asd sdff
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it. But can we put single quotes around ````toString(glue_collapse(asds, sep = " "))````

Comment: Thank you. Please see my edit.